# Ambiguous class name

Tags: c#, class, obsolete, ambiguous

If have a new project (ProjNew ) where I want to put several classes that are on other project (ProjOld).

The problem is I want to maintain the old classes marked with Obsolete to avoid running all my projects and check if they using it.

But in that way this may throw a ambiguous class name error because I didn't explicitly call by namespace.

Is there a way to say in the obsolete what assembly to use in ambiguity case?

Answer (score 4):

It is not entirely clear what you're asking, but I'll give it a try anyway.

Suppose you have two DLLs, old.dll and new.dll, both of which have a namespace N with a type C.  You can do this:

```
csc /r:NEW=new.dll /r:OLD=old.dll foo.cs
```

and then in foo.cs you can say

```
extern alias NEW;
extern alias OLD;
class D : NEW::N.C { }
class E : OLD::N.C { }
```

and D will inherit from the N.C in new.dll, E will inherit from the N.C in old.dll.

Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand your question, but this may help.  You can use a Using directive to clarify which class to use.  An example:
using ClassA = OldAssembly.ClassA;

Any references to ClassA will then refer to OldAssembly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the classes as [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28VS.80%29.aspx) and mark the methods you need to be obsolete.

This would allow you to divide your classes up into multiple files and still use the same class name.

Comment: Partial classes do not cross assembly boundaries.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that but it makes sense. Cheers for the heads up Eric.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your classes with [System.ObsoleteAttribute](http://System.ObsoleteAttribute)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MethodA();
    }

    [Obsolete("Use MethodB instead")]
    static void MethodA()
    {
    }

    static void MethodB()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this address the OPs need to have 2 classes with the same name? Can a class be marked as obsolete whilst having another class with the same name used in the same namespace? (by the looks of it, your example demonstrates marking a class member as obsolete, not the class itself)

Answer (score 0):

OK. It seems that if i add the same class to another namespace the ambiguos error it's just i happen in compile time.
I was afraid that it happen in run time to, but i test it and there was no problem.

Thanks